# JavaScript JSON - Value from nested data - SyntaxError in CodePens debug mode

Tags: javascript, json

I am no JavaScript expert, but after a long time of reading, experimenting and the power of Google and especially the results of stackoverflow I managed to work with the data of a REST API.

I made everything with CodePen, because it's nice to understand what I was doing.
Now I came to a problem that I can't solve myself. I tried to google it, but I think I just don't know the right keywords.

My problem is a SyntaxError which only occurs in debug mode. But I think my main problem is, that I understand how to get all values and work with all Object.keys and Object.values but not the correct way to get 1 specific value.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['

The JSON file looks like this:

```
[{"label":"Value","next":Value, ...},{"label":"Value","next":Value, ...}, ...]
```

My JavaScript Code looks like this:

```
const api_url = 'external json file';

async function getBrowsersData() {
    const response_api_url = await fetch(api_url_api_url);
    const data_api_url = await response_api_url.json();

    const data = data_api_url.[0].label;
```

The SyntaxError comes from the [0], what is the explained way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38682321/how-to-get-the-value-of-one-specific-json-key), if I understand it right.
If I use ["0"] as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32953428/get-specific-json-values-using-javascript), I get a SyntaxError in CodePen without Debug Mode.

Can someone please explain how I select the first label and, more importantly, why this works in CodePen, but not in its debug mode?
A link with a detailed description would help me too. I know it's probably a very simple question, but I am stuck and out of keywords I could search.

I have read [this excellent and very detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json) several times, but I do not understand my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you provide the codepen? It's hard to see exactly what you're doing wrong without full sample data

A quick issue I see is this though:

```
const data = data_browsers_30.[0].label;
```

should probably be:

```
const data = data_browsers_30[0].label;
```

That's the reason you get the SyntaxError; you don't need the . before [0].

if you think the label key is the issue this syntax is generally also valid:

```
const data = data_browsers_30[0]["label"]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
This was right: const data = data_browsers_30[0].label;
I still don't understand why it was working inside the CodePen.